# Can one learn meditation on their own?

Tags: vipassana, samatha, meditation-teachers

Can I learn Vipassana meditation or other Buddhist meditation techniques like Shamatha on my own using books and online videos? 
This is because it is sometimes hard to find good genuine teachers. 
Or do I definitely need to seek a teacher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to my understanding you can learn and start meditation (Samatha or Vipassana) using books and online videos. Of course there are some meditation practices which will be better to learn with a real teacher. Apart form that specially when you have any practical questions or troubles with the meditation or the practice, it is really helpful to get some advice from an experienced teacher.

Further, when you learn by yourself make sure to refer some credible resource (books or online videos) as there are a lot of verities available nowadays. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I started with books. I will go further in this path and will try to find meditation centers nearby. I just wanted to make sure if I wasn't going in a wrong path :)

Answer (score 5):

You can learn meditation with books and videos but it will be very difficult to find the truth and answers to your problems. So a better way is to find a teacher. Try to find a Sangha who teaches meditation. If you can't find one then try with books and others. Anyway my dear friends, never stop the meditation even if you can't find a teacher.

There is an order to meditate.

1. Sila
2. Samatha
3. Vipassana

Sila is following precepts with at least five for considerable time(it depends on person). 
Without Sila, samatha cannot be mastered. If someone try to use Samatha without Sila, they will understand that they are just wasting their time with increasing the tension. But with Sila you can feel the real cool nature of Buddhism.

Samatha meditation has 40 categories.

Kasina - 10
Asuba - 10
Anussathi - 10
Brahma Wihara - 4
Arupa - 4
Ahara prathikula Sagna - 1
Chathu Dhathu Wawaththana - 1

**Kasinas** concentrate on physical characteristics like color, heat and light.
**Asubhas**  concentrate on dead human bodies
**Anussathis** concentrate on reminding. **Anapanasathi** is reminding breath, **Budhhanussathi** is reminding characteristics of Lord Buddha, **Kayagathasathi** is concentrating about our body etc..
**Brahma Viharas** concentrates on Metta (friendliness with everyone), Karuna, Mudhitha and Upekka. 
others are not recommended without better knowledge.

You have to select one category according to your characteristics. After having a progress in samatha you can step in to Vipassana.

Vipassana meditation method is only included in Buddhism and first introduced by Lord Buddha. In this meditation method, we concentrates on three facts,

1. Anicca/Anitya
2. Dhukka
3. Anatta

**1. Anitya**

My dear friends, Anitya is the theory that says everything which is generated from a reason(s) will be destroyed due to the destruction of the reason.

**2. Dhukka**

If we make desire to objects(not only physical) that generated with a reason then we have to expect sadness after the destruction of the object due to the destruction of the reason (helped to exist of the object)

Think of how I love the shine of my car. Shine exist due to the paint and smoothness. If paint or smoothness are both gone, then shine will also disappear. Then because I loved the shine I will feel sad. 
Even when someone's car corroded completely I will not feel sad because I didn't like it.

With this logic Lord Buddha said that sad generates due to the craving towards something(Thanha) and not because of a God(s) or fate.

**3. Anatta**

with this Lord Buddha has said there is no thing called a soul in us. instead we have a mind. The mind is not a thing that exist the same all the time. It is born, exist and dies very, very quickly. So there is a time that the mind doesn't exist. At the time there was not a measurement to describe about the speed of the mind.

Once a Arhat Bhikkhu make a example to a king; think about 12 carts filled with rice seeds. You arrange all the seeds in a single line one after another. Then you can count all the seeds. Sir, there are more minds in a time of blink born, exist and dies. 
There are one and only one mind exist at once. Due to the massive speed you feel it as a one single mind. When this mind takes signals from the body and send signals to the body you feel the whole process as a soul.

That's the process we are going to understand in Vipassana meditation. Then can you imagine the power of samadhi you need to maintain to understand that rapid changes? You can do it. The path is not simple. but it is not impossible.

Namo Budhhaya..

Comment: I like the first section of your answer, all the rest doesn't seem to be answering the question. Why did you add that?

Comment: Good question dear friend, All the things I have included here are relevant to the question. First part directly answers the question and second part helps to find a good teacher and books. If your teacher doesn't know about those things or your book doesn't say about them then you have to think of other solution. I think my answer will help to lot of people to find good teachers and books for very successful vipassana meditation.

Answer (score 3):

[Introduction to Meditation: How To Meditate](http://youtu.be/hLvU7ppM4vE?list=PL603BD0B03E12F5A1)
For me, I find these videos very helpful.  There are many other videos that Bhante have on his site that talks about meditations.  You can also down load book from this site as well. http://www.sirimangalo.org/teachings/how-to-meditate/

Answer (score 0):

No matter what else, it will come from within. If you can learn it at all, a path already exists that may be found even by accident.

Each and every possible *teacher* you might find would have to have an unbroken link back to the *Original Teacher* if it wasn't possible. And the *Original Teacher* had to learn from within.

Whether innumerable missteps might be avoided easier with a teacher is a different question, but even missteps can teach valuable lessons if you choose to learn.

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say "have an unbroken link back to the original teacher", do you mean Gautama Buddha? Because I believe Siddhartha Gautama worked with 2 teachers before going off on his own. _/\\_

Comment: Consider the case of having two teachers. Either both worked with a single previous or each worked with a different one. If different, then go back another level. At some point, the lines either converge, in which case we only need to follow a single line, or they don't in which case we follow two single lines. Regardless, at some point, every line has a starting point where there was no previous teacher. Whenever (any) _Original Teacher_ is reached, it's a demonstration that it's possible to learn without a teacher. There is more, but that's enough to accept possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I've attended courses run by my local Rigpa group - perhaps there is one near you that you can try out? http://www.rigpa.org/

I have also benefited greatly from the Headspace app https://www.headspace.com/ -- I think Andy is a great teacher for the on-line medium!

Hope this helps - good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism SE! I think the first part of your answer doesn't really answer the OP's question. He/she want to learn to meditate without taking classes. As for the second part, what exactly makes the Headspace app so great?

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism SE! In the current form, this is more of a comment like a quick reference than an answer to the question.  I would suggest formatting you answer to explain why these links answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the rigpa link. They seem to be there in many locations. About headspace, I am not a fan of secular meditation. I would like my meditation to retain Buddhist elements. I read a quote of Bikkhu Bodhi about secular meditation which was something like, you get stress relief and would make you a more compassionate person but it would not take you a step closer to nirvana.

Answer (score 0):

When you meditate there are sometimes "storms" or big mental disturbances that happen. So it is generally advise to have a guidance of a teacher through this is not necessary. What generally happens is you react and worsen the situation.

No matter what you should not loose the balance of your mind. You should be always equanimous. If you can do this there then you are fit to do meditation through books and other sources without a guidance of a teacher.

Answer (score 0):

any place to start is the right place, just start.
Don't be too concerned about finding the right teacher or spiritual path. There is a true saying: 
When the student is ready, the master will appear.
He, or she, will come running to inspire you, when the time is right, never before. 
Please remember that everything is actually pre ordained. Just start.
Very best wishes and have a great week, Rajpal.