# Is there any Buddhist society / group / organisation in Mumbai, India? Where we can meet similar like minded people, attend cultural events

Tags: theravada, teaching

I am looking for some kind of Buddhist society/group/organization in Mumbai, India, where we can meet similar like-minded people, attend cultural events, discuss/talk/teachings (dharma talk) on Buddhist ideas/concepts, etc. I am looking for Theravada Buddhism & not neo-Buddhism. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

I know there's COVID situation going on but I just need to know if there's any, will attend when the situation becomes normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [9 listed here](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/search.php?keyword=mumbai&search=Search&country_id=0&province_id=0&tradition%5B%5D=theravada) -- that search is filtering on "Mumbai" and "Theravada".

Answer (score 1):

I just searched on Google and found the [Global Vipassana Pagoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Vipassana_Pagoda), Gorai, North-west of Mumbai.

This is their website: https://www.globalpagoda.org/

This is obviously a Buddhist organization associated with [S.N. Goenka](https://www.globalpagoda.org/mr-s-n-goenka). It's his Vipassana movement, teaching [Vipassana meditation](https://www.globalpagoda.org/vipassana-meditation-need-of-the-hour) based on the teachings of [Sayagyi U Ba Khin](https://www.globalpagoda.org/sayagyi-u-ba-khin).

Therefore, it's Theravada.

Comment: That's for meditation, which I do on a daily basis. And its 10-day course is hard to get short-listed & me being the only earning of the family I can't afford it either way.

Comment: @VarunKrish Please see the question [Is it fine to learn Vipassana meditation online?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/36321/471), especially the answer by Ven. Yuttadhammo.